# Connecting with pypardot after the changes

Tags: salesforce, pardot

For the past years I've been connecting to Pardot with the usual email-password way that it is described at the [pypardot documentation](https://github.com/mneedham91/PyPardot4). 
This obviously stopped working after the changes of Spring 21, but I cannot seem to find a good guide on alternative ways of connecting to the api.

I would appreciate some technical direction, examples or guides since documentations like [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5) are too vague in my opinion and don't provide more practical help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to get a Salesforce Access token prior to accessing the Pardot API.

I wrote a blog post on the details on what is needed to get connected, check it out: https://thespotforpardot.com/2021/02/02/pardot-api-and-getting-ready-with-salesforce-sso-users-part-3b-connecting-to-pardot-api-from-code/